# C# DevExpress very small size of caret in XtraEdits at first of text

Tags: devexpress, right-to-left, farsi

I use DevExpress component. When I use XtraEditors such as `EditText`, `ComboBoxEdit` or `LookUpEdit`, the size of the caret becomes very small when the focus is at the beginning of the text (or on an empty box).

The reason for this problem is the use of Persian language and choosing the right to left control feature. Is there a way to solve this problem?

[image: Caret]

Comment: Have you tried contacting DevExpress support for a solution? It's their code and components - they ought to know what you can do to fix this problem

Comment: I raised this question in DevExpress support, but unfortunately they haven't responded in a few days.